How to vary subplot spacing with nested gridspecs and constrained layout?
I'm trying to make 3 pairs of subplots, with more space between the pairs.  But I can't independently change the space between the pairs.
I'm using nested GridSpecs following this answer.
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

layout = "constrained"
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 6), layout=layout)
fig.suptitle(f"{layout=}")

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, figure=fig, hspace=0.2)
for g in gs:
    sub_gs = g.subgridspec(2, 1, hspace=0.1)
    for gg in sub_gs:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(gg)
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False, direction="in")

fig.savefig(f"test-{layout}.png")
plt.show()

When layout = None the spacing makes sense (3 groups of 2 subplots); when layout = "constrained" it doesn't...In fact, the outer GridSpec's hspace has no effect at all when layout = "constrained".  Instead, the outer GridSpec's spacing only responds to the h_pad of the layout engine, which affects all subplots (see Constrained Layout Guide # Padding and spacing).
 
How can I get the result on the left using constrained layout, so that e.g. the subplots fill the whole figure, a colorbar can easily be added spanning all 6 subplots, etc?

I don't know if it's possible to achieve this level of control with nested GridSpecs and a constrained layout.
I ended up using insets instead.  Then the space between the pairs of plots can be controlled with hspace and the space within each pair can be controlled manually via the inset size (space variable below).
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

layout = "constrained"
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    3, 1, figsize=(2, 6), gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0.2), layout=layout
)
fig.suptitle(f"{layout=}")

space = 0.1
height = (1 - space) / 2
for ax in axs:
    ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)
    ax.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
    inset1 = ax.inset_axes((0, height + space, 1, height))
    inset2 = ax.inset_axes((0, 0, 1, height))
    for inset in (inset1, inset2):
        inset.tick_params(labelbottom=False, labelleft=False, direction="in")

fig.savefig(f"test-{layout}.png")

 
